# Undo reduction of LVM

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm

So I did something stupid while trying to solve my another issue by redoing (I thought) what I had done[1].

I ran the following command, think the number what the volume amount that I wanted to remove, not the size that was going to be set for the LVM:
**sudo lvreduce -L 1,8T /dev/server-vg/root**

So now all the stuff on the other part of the LVM is gone - like many commands since the LVM was on top of a RAID0.

Is there any way of readding that part that I removed? Undoing what I just did?

I have backup, but I'd rather see if this is possible to do first.

I have tried to reset the size to the size that ought to be before I added the third disk (see [1]):

```
**sudo lvresize -L 3,7T /dev/server-vg/root**
```

And also tried to just use all that is available:

```
**sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/server-vg/root**
```

Both gives me:
**Command failed with status code 5.**

1: [Extend LUKS with physical drive. Unsure if new drive encrypts files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923112/extend-luks-with-physical-drive-unsure-if-new-drive-encrypts-files)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the lvm config backups in /etc/lvm/archive and if you can find the one with the correct settings ( should be the most recent ), then resture it with `vgcfgrestore`

Comment: Found it. Tried to restore but it says "Couldn't find the device with uuid XYZ" [...] " Cannot restore Volume group server-vg with 1 PVs makes as missing"

Comment: Ah, hold on. It is because of the third drive that I've since removed.

Comment: Ok. I have restores the VG now. I had to comment out everything about sdd (which I have formated since, and am unable to do a vgcreate on, for some reason now). I still have an issue with the superblock stating one number, but that the phsical size says something else.

Comment: Should I try some resize again or something? What is the worst thing I could try and do?

Comment: @DanielHolm, if you restored the working configuration prior to the resize, you are done.

Comment: I've tried all of my three backups. Some thing. The superblock is still larger than the actually size.

Comment: @DanielHolm, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: when I try to run a fsck or mount the encrypted partition in the LVM that I have restored it states that "The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 1463152640 blocks
The physical size of the device is 974774272 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!"

Comment: How is it not possible to change that superblock size? I've tried to use backup blocks, resize this and that. But this error remains.

Comment: @DanielHolm, it isn't superblock size, it is the size of the partition.  You still have not managed to restore a configuration prior to the resize, where the partition was larger.

Comment: I have tried all (three) of the backup configuration. Nothing changes. Still size issue. Unable to resize, do a file system check. I guess it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clear answer, but the issue is solved. What I did was to resotr a previous lvm config (though I had formated sdd since, I had do modify the backup file to change the ID to be the new ID of sdd. Then I ran kvpm. It said 6TB as it should. Then I renamed the group (I have done a new system install and the names were the same). At that point the size said 4TB. I than extended the logical volume, and resizing the file system as well. It gave a few errors but the filesystem is now mounted and my files are there.